# Copy subtilles while watching video in VLC media player

Tags: python

I want to write a python script which copies a part of the subtitles while playing a film from the VLC media player, e.g. when I press F10 while watching a film, the script goes to the subtitles, e.g. subtitles.srt, and searches for and copies the subtitles which are then displayed on the screen, then copies the given phrase to the results.txt file.
The program runs in a loop.

```
import keyboard
from pywinauto import Application
import re


def get_current_playback_time():
    # Spróbuj znaleźć okno VLC Media Player
    try:
        app = Application().connect(title_re=".*VLC media player.*")
        vlc_window = app.window(title_re=".*VLC media player.*")
        vlc_window.set_focus()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while finding VLC Media Player window: {str(e)}")
        return None

    # Pobierz czas odtwarzania z okna VLC
    playback_time = None
    try:
        window_text = vlc_window.window_text()
        time_match = re.search(r"(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)", window_text)
        if time_match:
            hours = int(time_match.group(1))
            minutes = int(time_match.group(2))
            seconds = int(time_match.group(3))
            playback_time = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while reading playback time: {str(e)}")

    return playback_time


def save_subtitle_fragment(playback_time):
    # Otwórz plik z napisami
    with open('napisy.srt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        subtitles = file.read()

    # Znajdź fragment napisów na podstawie czasu
    pattern = r"\d+\n(\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) --> (\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)\n(.*?)\n\n"
    matches = re.findall(pattern, subtitles, re.DOTALL)

    for match in matches:
        start_time = match[0]
        end_time = match[1]
        subtitle_text = match[2]

        if convert_time_format(start_time) <= playback_time * 1000 <= convert_time_format(end_time):
            # Zapisz fragment do pliku wyniki.txt
            with open('wyniki.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.write(subtitle_text)
            break


def convert_time_format(time_string):
    hours, minutes, seconds = re.split(r"[:,]", time_string)
    milliseconds = int(seconds[-3:])
    seconds = int(seconds[:-3])
    return int(hours) * 3600000 + int(minutes) * 60000 + seconds * 1000 + milliseconds


# Funkcja wywoływana po naciśnięciu klawisza F10
def on_f10_press(event):
    if event.name == 'f10':
        playback_time = get_current_playback_time()
        if playback_time is not None:
            save_subtitle_fragment(playback_time)


# Zarejestruj zdarzenie dla klawisza F10
keyboard.on_press(on_f10_press)

# Uruchom w nieskończoność, aby nasłuchiwać zdarzeń klawiszy
keyboard.wait()
```

Unfortunately, nothing was generated for me in the results.txt file.

Comment: Use a debugger or add some `print`s to find out where the script fails.

Comment: I don't really know how to use a debugger, sorry, I think the code is not working due to the inability to download the date from VLC player but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: Then add `print`s which e. g. show what time your code extracted from the VLC window (if any).

Comment: Playback Time: None  I added instruction error

Comment: Add more prints, especially what is the  `window_text` retrieved from VLC window?